# Select a row with just one value in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is my table looks:

(I don't say it before, colum2 is string type, not an integer, sorry about it)

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ USER ║ COLOR ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ a    ║ Red   ║
║ b    ║ Blue  ║
║ c    ║ Blue  ║
║ b    ║ Red   ║
║ a    ║ Red   ║
║ c    ║ White ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

I've just need the rows which has *exclusively* color=  "Red". 
It must return "a" ("b" contains value "Blue" too).

How can I set the select? Thanks and regards

Comment: Just curious, why can't you use count or any other agrr. function? What is the expected output? Just one column = RED?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  column1
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Column1
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT column2) = 1
        AND MAX(column2) = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/938d5/1)

here's another way,

```
SELECT  column1
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Column1
HAVING  MAX(column2) = MIN(column2) AND
        MAX(column2) = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/938d5/3)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  user
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY user
HAVING  SUM(color = 'red') = COUNT(*)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a82e9/2)

Answer (score 0):

The more efficient way to do this is by comparing the `min` and `max` values:

```
select column1
from t
group by column1
having min(column2) = max(column2) and min(column2) = 1
```

If the column can take on NULL values, you will need to exclude those as well:

```
select column1
from t
group by column1
having min(column2) = max(column2) and min(column2) = 1 and count(column2) = count(*)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select distinct Column1 from Table1 Where Column2='1'
```

Or if it is integer then:

```
Select distinct Column1 from Table1 Where Column2=1
```

Assuming that Table1 is the table name

Comment: This would still find rows where it may have a companion with a 0 value.